# Maps and the number of elements in a map

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So here's the question:

Suppose $f: S \to T$ is a map of sets. 
a. If T is finite & the map is one-to-one, show that $|S|$ is finite and that $|S| \le |T|$.

b. If S is finite & the map is onto, show that $|T|$ is finite and that $|T|  ≤ |S|.$ 

So here's what I understand: (or think I understand)

for a: Suppose $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in S$. 
Suppose $|S| > |T|$. 
Then $f: S \to T$ would be $x_1 = f(x_1)$, $x_2 = f(x_2)$, $x_3 = f(x_2).$
This is a contradiction because $f$ is not one-to-one. 
 Therefore,  $|S|  \le |T|$.

And my guess would be b. would be the same thing but for proving onto.

Is this the correct way of going about this problem? Thank you!

Comment: LaTeX commands you might want to know: $\to$ is `$\to$`, $\le$ is `$\le$`, $\in$ is `$\in$`, and $x_1$ is `$x_1$`

Comment: You have the right general idea.  Your proof as written only works if $S$ has exactly $3$ elements, though.  Can we use the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)?

Comment: how would I prove for more than 3? thanks!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i looked into that principle and i still don't really get it... any other hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first part would go something like this:

Let $T$ be finite and the map one to one. Suppose that $n=|S|> |T|=m$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be an enumeration of the elements of $S$ and $y_1,\dots, y_m$ an enumeration of the elements of $T$.

We note that each of the $n$ elements $f(x_i)$ is an element of the set $T=\{y_1,\dots,y_m\}$. By the pigeonhole principle, there exist two such elements that are equal. That is, there exist integers $i\neq j$ between $1$ and $n$ for which $f(x_i)=f(x_j)$. This is a contradiction of the map being one to one.

The conclusion follows.